# Adding Data Label to Excel Chart - Time Consuming

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have a code that adds a data label to the selected point on a chart. The section of code below takes about 4 seconds. And that is too long for the take I am working on. Any ideas?

My computer has reasonable specs. and I am using Office 2013.[image]

```
        Set SRS = ChartObjects.SeriesCollection(Arg1)
        If SRS.Points(Arg2).HasDataLabel = False Then
            ChartObjects.SeriesCollection(Arg1).Points(Arg2).HasDataLabel = True
            ChartObjects.SeriesCollection(Arg1).Points(Arg2).DataLabel.Text = "Case: #" + CStr(CaseCoUnter)
            Select Case True
                Case Upper
                    ChartObjects.SeriesCollection(Arg1).Points(Arg2).DataLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
                Case Lower
                    ChartObjects.SeriesCollection(Arg1).Points(Arg2).DataLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionBelow
            End Select

        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I too have an Intel processor, but at a slightly lower speed of 2.60 GHz, and only 8 GB of RAM.  Nevertheless, when I tested your posted code, I clicked on a data point and it  added the data label somewhat instantaneously.  So if it's taking about 4 seconds for you, it may be because you have other code within the event procedure that is slowing it down.  In any case, your code could be re-written as follows...

```
    Set SRS = ChartObjects.SeriesCollection(Arg1)
    With SRS.Points(Arg2)
        If .HasDataLabel = False Then
            .HasDataLabel = True
            .DataLabel.Text = "Case: #" + CStr(CaseCoUnter)
            Select Case True
                Case Upper
                    .DataLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
                Case Lower
                    .DataLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionBelow
            End Select
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: Would it be because I have over 200,000 data points. The way I am handling it, I am only viewing ~2hrs of data (data point per second) . But the chart is referencing the entire data set.

Comment: Quite possibly, but you can check it for yourself by testing with a much smaller number of data points.

Comment: It sure was - got to figure out how to handle this in a better manner. Perhaps using access as my database. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Having that many points will definitely slow down the code. Could you possibly limit the number of points in the chart rather than containing all the points but most of them are off scale?